# U-boot pipe command output

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, u-boot

In U-boot is it possible to pipe the output of a command to a variable:

```
U-Boot: ping 192.168.0.0.1 | ping_res
U-Boot: printenv ping_res
```

Thanks

Comment: The standard CLI of U-Boot can be replaced with the Hush shell, but its capabilities do not seem to include pipes (U-Boot does not have multitasking) nor I/O redirection.  See http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CommandLineParsing BTW your example of a pipe and variable assignment is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The standard CLI of U-Boot can be replaced with the Hush shell, but its capabilities do not seem to include pipes (U-Boot does not have multitasking) nor I/O redirection. See http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/CommandLineParsing.

Note: your example of a pipe and variable assignment is incorrect.

(Answer created from [@sawdust's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855776/u-boot-pipe-command-output#comment42277861_26855776))